# Why slow netfilter hook function, cause the system crash?

Tags: c, crash, kernel-module, netfilter

The below code is a simple netfilter hook module. When add `msleep(500);` to `main_hook` function, system crashed.

What is the problem?

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/mutex.h>

#include <linux/netdevice.h>
#include <linux/netfilter.h>
#include <linux/netfilter_ipv4.h>

#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <net/ip.h>

#include <linux/tcp.h>
#include <net/tcp.h>
#include <linux/inet.h>
#include<linux/delay.h>

static struct mutex critical_section;

unsigned int main_hook(unsigned int hooknum,
                       struct sk_buff *skb,
                       const struct net_device *in,
                       const struct net_device *out,
                       int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff*))
{
    if (skb)
    {
        mutex_lock(&critical_section);
        msleep(500); // <------ Adding this line cause the system crashes.
        mutex_unlock(&critical_section);
    }
    return NF_ACCEPT;
}

static int __init my_device_module_init(void)
{
    mutex_init(&critical_section);

    netfilter_ops_out.hook                  =       main_hook;
    netfilter_ops_out.pf                    =       NFPROTO_IPV4;
    netfilter_ops_out.hooknum               =       NF_INET_POST_ROUTING;
    netfilter_ops_out.priority              =       NF_IP_PRI_FIRST;

    nf_register_hook(&netfilter_ops_out); /* register NF_IP_POST_ROUTING hook */

    return 0;
}

static void __exit my_device_module_exit(void)
{
    nf_unregister_hook(&netfilter_ops_out); /*unregister NF_IP_POST_ROUTING hook*/
    return;
}

module_init(my_device_module_init);
module_exit(my_device_module_exit);
```

Comment: What is the crash you are getting? Not that I'm surprised, since sleeping in kernel is generally a BAD THING(tm), it's just that I'm sure the error message will contain SOMETHING useful... In particular, sleeping inside a LOCK is a particularly bad thing, as it tends to create deadlocks where something else tries to grab that lock.

Comment: I do `msleep(500);` for simulating a time consuming task.

Comment: And what crash do you get - and no, I don't think sleeping inside a lock for half a second is a good idea. That will cause all sorts of problems, quite possibly including that the kernel triggers "I seem to have got stuck" or "You shouldn't be sleeping with locks on" type errors.

Comment: You're most probably sleeping from an interrupt, which you cannot. Interrupts cannot lock.